# How to do IP whitelisting dynamically in the spring boot application?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-data

I want to give access to whitelisted users without considering the token from them. The authorization server is different spring boot application which provides token to access resource on spring boot application that I am working on. Now I have one API endpoint to add IP in whitelist. Currently I am using IP whitelisting in following manner-

```
public class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    IpWhitelistingProvider ipWhitelistingProvider;
    
    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        
        http
        .authorizeRequests()
        
        .antMatchers("/api/**").access(ipWhitelistingProvider.acessString()+"#oauth2.hasScope('resourcescope')")
//...
}
```

The ipwhitelistingprovider.accessString() provides expression- hasIpAdress(1st ip in list) or hasIpAddress(2nd ip in list) and so on ....
The problem here is I can't update these expression dynamically, it only updated at application startup. So when I add new IP through API that I have previously mentioned, it won't update the expression inside access method. For updating that I need to restart the application. So how can I do it so that ip added dynamically will be available to the security?

Comment: Write the proper expression, something like `@ipWhitelistingProvider.accessString` which will call that method during evaluation. Or just write a method that takes an ip-address and does the validation something like `!ipWhitelistingService.isAllowed(#ipAddress) and #oauth.hasScope('resourcescope')`. Which will call the method, which in turn can query the database and do the validation.

Comment: I strongly suggest that you readup on how SPeL works. The way you have written it now it will only be called once, they way I written it (as part of an expression) it will be called each time.

Comment: Please readup on SPeL. How to access beans and how to write a proper expression. The problem with your current approach is that you create an expression containing the list of ip-addresses, where mine is dynamic and will always be executed. But as stated read how to construct expressions and do bean references

Comment: I have tried with ----- .antMatchers("/api  /**").access("@ipWhitelistingProvider.acessString(request) or #oauth2.hasScope('resourcescope')").--- But it showing following error-Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1057E: No bean resolver registered in the context to resolve access to bean 'ipWhitelistingProvider'   ----

Comment: Your expression wouldn't work, it would need to return a `boolean` not `String` to re-evaluate the expression again. Also make sure you use the correct bean0name in the expression.